# Rebind backspace to C-d for deleting char backwards

Tags: key-bindings, deletion

I want to delete char backwards using `C-d`, not the backspace key. I could do it like that:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "\C-d") 'delete-backward-char)
```

However, I have noticed that in fact backspace points to different functions in different major modes. For example, in lisp-mode it is `backward-delete-char-untabify` function, in C mode `c-electric-backspace`, in Help mode it is `cua-scroll-down`. Is it possible to emulate backspace behaviour with `C-d` without remapping it for every major mode separately?
I also tried this:

```
 (global-set-key (kbd "\C-d") (kbd "<DEL>"))
```

But it obviously turns every `C-d` key into `<DEL>`, so keybindings such `C-c C-d` stop working, making this not a suitable solution either.

P.S. I am slightly suprised that (as it seems after some googling) not so many people rebind backspace key. You have to take away your hand from home  row every time you need to delete a character! This is so uncomfortable...how do you, Emacs people, delete characters?

Comment: I use `delete-backward-char` instead of rebinding `<DEL>` and it works so far for me.

Comment: You say "it obviously turns every `C-d` key into `<DEL>`, so keybindings such as `C-c C-d` stop working" - are you sure about that? When you press `C-c` (or `C-x`, or `C-h`) another keymap becomes active, in which `C-d` should NOT be overwritten. As per this doc: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Keys.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "C-d") (kbd "DEL"))
```

to make the `C-c C-d` work, one can

```
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "DEL") (kbd "C-d") )
```

that is, when you need to press C-d in some key, press backspace instead.

I don't think this remap is a good idea. You trade moving hand and possibly twisting wrist by requiring 2 keys, involving a pinky.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try

```
(bind-key* "C-d" (kbd "<DEL>"))
```

- `(kbd "<DEL>")` is keyboard macro and a command definition. I guess you can also use something like `(lambda () (interactive) (call-interactively (key-binding (kbd "<DEL>"))))` if you prefer.
- `bind-key*` will bind `C-d` and override any mode-specific binding of `C-d`. (this function is from `bind-key.el`, which is part of the `use-package` project)

By the way, to cancel the effect of the above code

```
(unbind-key "C-d" override-global-map)
```