# Key binding to issue another key binding

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

Is there a way to configure emacs so that a key binding will just issue another one?
In particular, I want to configure it so that `C-t` replicates (or even better replaces) `backspace`. I couldn't find a way to do it in my Window Manager (I am not even sure if it is at all possible in any Window Manger) so I have to do it in Emacs.

At the moment, I am just mapping `C-t` to `backward-delete-char` but this is not ideal,
because many packages map `backspace` and I would have to go over all keymaps and replace `backspace` with `C-t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A key sequence is just one possible form of a command.
So you can just use the following form (if I understand your question right):

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "C-t") (kbd "<backspace>"))
```

You can replace <kbd>backspace</kbd> with <kbd>C-t</kbd> by translating it in `input-decode-map`:

```el
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-t") (kbd "<backspace>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "<backspace>") [7])
```

The second form replaces <kbd>backspace</kbd> with the ASCII bell character. The harmless `keyboard-quit` command is bound to that character.

---

Note that there is already [a duplicate of this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/28230/2370) **but the following statement in that question is wrong**:

> I also tried this:
>
> ```el
>  (global-set-key (kbd "\C-d") (kbd "<DEL>"))
> ```
>
> But it obviously turns every C-d key into , so keybindings such C-c C-d stop working, making this not a suitable solution either.

See also the [corresponding comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28230/rebind-backspace-to-c-d-for-deleting-char-backwards#comment43226_28230) of [VanLaser](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/8708/vanlaser):

> You say "it obviously turns every C-d key into , so keybindings such as C-c C-d stop working" - are you sure about that? When you press C-c (or C-x, or C-h) another keymap becomes active, in which C-d should NOT be overwritten. As per this doc: https://gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Keys.html

Comment: That's exactly it. Thanks for this. Is there a way to replace the backspace rather than replicate it? So somehow map `<backspace>` to `'ignore` and map `C-t` to whatever `<backspace>` was mapped to.

Comment: @Tohiko See `C-h i g (elisp)Remapping Commands`

Comment: @phils He does not want to remap the `delete-backward-char` command since depending on the major mode many other commands are bound to the `DEL` key.