# Rebinding C-d to delete-backward-char

Tags: key-bindings

`M-x global-set-key <RET> C-d delete-backward-char` successfully rebinds `C-d` to `delete-backward-char`.

However, `(global-set-key (kbd "C-d") 'delete-backward-char)` in my `~/.emacs.d/init.el` doesn't seem to have any effect.
[This related post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28230/rebind-backspace-to-c-d-for-deleting-char-backwards) doesn't solve it for me.

I am new to emacs, is there something wrong with the way I am entering my command in my init file.
Note that other commands successfully working in my init file include ones such as:

`(global-set-key (kbd "C-c a") #'org-agenda)`.

I don't understand why the `#` is needed here, but using a `#` did not solve my problem of remapping `C-d`

**Edit**

Removing

```
(org-babel-do-load-languages
'org-babel-load-languages
'(
   (emacs-lisp . t)
   (R . t)
   (python . t)
   (scheme . t)
   (java . t))
   (latex . t)
)
```

from my `~/.emacs` file causes things to work. But I would like to be able to keep these lines if possible. Any idea why these lines are problematic?

Comment: When testing with an init file, with only the line you mention here, `C-d` correctly triggers the command `delete-backward-char` (i.e. it deletes the inserted characters). What does `C-h k` `C-d` tell you? Placing `#'` before a symbol is called 'sharp quoting' its use and purpose is explained [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/35989/26163).

Comment: What's the mode of the buffer where `C-d` is not working? It may be that it overrides the global keymap setting with its own. @dalanicolai's comment tells you how to check.

Comment: `#'` is an abbreviation for `function`. See the Elisp manual, node [Anonymous Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Anonymous-Functions.html).

Comment: @dalanicolai `C-h k C-d` says that C-d runs the command delete-char (found in global-map). It seems that some lines in my .emacs file are causing problems, as shown in my update.  I am testing things out in the scratch buffer and it works when I remove the problematic lines

Comment: To me, it looks like the parenthesis that is placed after `(java . t)` should really be placed after `(latex . t)`. Otherwise, try to start Emacs via `emacs --debug-iinit`.

Comment: thanks, I will try that

Comment: You mention `~/.emacs.d/init.el` **and** `~/.emacs`. Note, that Emacs loads [only one of them](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Find-Init.html) if you do not explicitly call `(load "~/.emacs.d/init.el")` in `~/.emacs`. If you put `(global-set-key (kbd "C-d") 'delete-backward-char)` into `~/.emacs.d/init.el` and a non-empty `~/.emacs` exists (without `(load "~/.emacs.d/init.el")`) then the `global-set-key` is never evaluated.